# Is there a way to create a range of sum of multiple columns matching a condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a data frame which contains an experimental `CONDITION` which has an determined `INDEX`. Each experiment has a `NAME-A` associated and a `NAME_B` corresponding to a specific `NAME_A`.

My main objective is to summarize total of `NAME-A` and `NAME-B` by `CONDITION` by creating a range considering the difference of `INDEX` value between two consecutives `NAME_A` , i.e. the difference between indexes for the same `CONDITION` should not be grater than  400 (**INDEX[i+1] - INDEX[i] < 400**).

Possible escenarios are `NAME_A` can be duplicated, but not `NAME_B`. `NAME_A` can have no `NAME_B` associated and so count can differ between columns.

Here I leave an example in `a` is the input data I have and `b` should be the output.

```
a <- data.frame(c(1,2,2,2,2,3),c(1,1,50,400,900,1),c("A","B","B","C","D","E"),
                c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5",NA))
colnames(a) <- c("CONDITION","INDEX","NAME_A","NAME_B")
```

**Data**

```
  CONDITION INDEX NAME_A NAME_B
1         1     1      A     X1
2         2     1      B     X2
3         2    50      B     X3
4         2   400      C     X4
5         2   900      D     X5
6         3     1      E   <NA>
```

**Desire Output**

```
b <- data.frame(c(1,2,2,3),c(1,1,900,1),c(1,400,900,1),c("A","B, C","D","E"),c(1,2,1,1),
                c("X1","X2, X3, X4","X5",NA),c(1,3,1,0))
colnames(b) <- c("CONDITION","INDEX_MIN","INDEX_MAX",
                 "NAME_A","COUNT_A","NAME_B","COUNT_B")

  CONDITION INDEX_MIN INDEX_MAX NAME_A COUNT_A     NAME_B COUNT_B
1         1         1         1      A       1         X1       1
2         2         1       400   B, C       2 X2, X3, X4       3
3         2       900       900      D       1         X5       1
4         3         1         1      E       1       <NA>       0
```

My problem is that I've made this separately for `NAME-A` and `NAME-B` but as shown in example, sometimes `NAME-A` has no `NAME-B` associated so the result range windows are not equally distributed between data frames, and so further manual edition is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can `group_by` CONDITION, then use `summarise` to determine the other columns. Of note, I have used underscores instead of hyphens column names (otherwise if using non-standard names, wrap them in backticks).

To address the difference of no greater than 400 in INDEX between rows, you can assign a GROUP number with `cumsum` that will increment within a given CONDITION when the difference in INDEX exceeds 400. Then you can use this in your `group_by` statement before summarising.

Note that the `n_distinct(NAME_B, na.rm = TRUE)` can be substituted with `sum(!is.na(NAME_B))` as NAME_B cannot be duplicated.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  group_by(CONDITION) %>%
  group_by(GROUP = cumsum(c(1, diff(INDEX) > 400)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(
    INDEX_MIN = min(INDEX),
    INDEX_MAX = max(INDEX),
    COUNT_A = n_distinct(NAME_A),
    NAME_A = toString(unique(NAME_A)), 
    COUNT_B = n_distinct(NAME_B, na.rm = TRUE),
    NAME_B = toString(NAME_B)
  )
```

**Output**

```
  CONDITION GROUP INDEX_MIN INDEX_MAX COUNT_A NAME_A COUNT_B NAME_B    
      <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>     
1         1     1         1         1       1 A            1 X1        
2         2     1         1       400       2 B, C         3 X2, X3, X4
3         2     2       900       900       1 D            1 X5        
4         3     2         1         1       1 E            0 NA
```

**Data**

```
a <- structure(list(CONDITION = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), INDEX = c(1, 
1, 50, 400, 900, 1), NAME_A = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
    NAME_B = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It worked, but there is something missing. I want to make a range using `INDEX`, lets say that a specific range is formed when the difference between indexes is not greater than 400 in a `CONDITION` and then count `NAME-A` and `NAME-B` within that range.

Comment: @PauloAlvarez Did you want to go through for each CONDITION/NAME_A combination, look at the range in INDEX, and then add rows of data to ensure that the maximum different in INDEX never exceeds 400? So, for example, if for CONDITION of 2, NAME_A of B, the difference is 50; but if it was 600, then would create two rows where INDEX is 400 with different NAME_B, so the INDEX range would be from 1-400 and 400-600?

Comment: Thank to you I realized I formulated really wrong my question so I edditted. You understood wht I was looking forward. The general idea is to make a difference between the indexes to create a new condition and then summarize how many NAME_A and NAME_B I have for each original CONDITION.

Comment: @PauloAlvarez Please see edited answer - does this accomplish your goal?